# StdIn not working... @ Linux

Tags: java, linux

Below is the program.. I tried after moving jars also... Is moving enough ? or any extra task to do with the jar files .

```
public class Stack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
        }
    }
}
```

i moved necessary jar(stdlib.jar,algs4.jar ) files to lib ..... But it still showing the error.......

Stack.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
           while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
                   ^
  symbol:   variable StdIn
  location: class Stack
1 error

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup your [classpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_%28Java%29) to use external java libraries

If you are using eclipse, you could `Project - > Properties -> Java build path ->add Jar`.
That jar file should be placed in a directory inside your workspace (`lib/` for example)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you got this `Stdin.isEmpty()` stuff from, but this does not bear any resemblance to any *standard* Java APIs.

The simple way to read from standard input in Java is to do something like this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and then call methods on the `scanner` object to read stuff.  Refer to the javadocs for [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for details of how to use it.

---

On the other hand, if `Stdin` is a real class that you have written, or that is defined in some 3rd-party library (maybe "stdlib.jar"?), then the problem is:

- the directory or JAR file containing the class is not on your classpath, or
- you haven't imported into this class, or
- both of the above.

The procedure for adding something to the classpath depends on how you are building (i.e. compiling) the code, and how you are then running it.

Answer (score 0):

`StdIn` is not a Java keyword or class in the `java.lang` package. In order to use a class defined in your jars you must include the jar in your classpath and import the package or class to your class.